# What's the difference between 我是老师 or 我当老师?

Tags: difference, meaning-in-context

Sometimes when I take a [滴滴打车](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Didi_Dache) taxi to the university campus, the driver asks me if I'm a student, and I reply something along the lines of:

> 我是老师
>   I'm a teacher
>   <sub>Wǒ shì lǎoshī</sub>

As far as I can tell, this is grammatically correct.  However, more than once, the driver replied:

> 你当老师
>   You're a teacher
>   <sub>Nǐ dāng lǎoshī</sub>

It feels almost like they're correcting me, but I don't really understand why.  It's possible 我是老师 sounds more along the lines of what a child might say as it's very simple.  (It's also possible I simply misheard them.)

**Question**: What's the difference between 我是老师 or 我当老师?

Among the zillions of meanings of [当](http://dict.cn/%E5%BD%93), one is "to act as", so maybe 我当老师 has a meaning closer to "I perform the role of a teacher".  But I still see no concrete reason that 我是老师 is wrong or inferior.

Comment: If that driver is questioning, that driver is just to confirm if you are truly a teacher and there is nothing wrong with 我是老师. It could be couple of reasons: 1. he didn't hear you well. 2. You look too young to be a teacher. Or there might be some other reasons which made him suspicious. If he said it as an affirmative sentence, it's like saying "oh, I see it. (you are a teacher)"

Comment: "我是老师" is pretty fine. The only thing I can guess is that the driver wants to response to your with more respect, especially when used with "您"; e.g. "您当老师啊".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

我**是**老师 = I **am** a teacher" It is completely correct

当 is a verb that means 'to be/ working as/ take on the role or position of'

你**当**老师= you **being** a teacher

你**来当**老师 = you'll **be** a teacher

你**去当**老师 = you go and **be** a teacher

你**当上了**老师 = you've **became** a teacher

> *The driver's question "你当老师?" (you being a teacher?) was a rhetorical one. That imply "It is hard to believe people as young as you would be a teacher." He could had asked "你是老师?" and the meaning would be the same.*