# How does 一个， 一位，一名 change the meaning of a sentence?

Tags: measure-word

I saw two versions of a sentence "He is a teacher":

> 他是老师。 VS 他是一个老师。

After googling I've become even more confused by versions:

> 他是一位老师。 AND 他是一名老师。

Are they actually different? What is the difference? Is it possible to use these ‘一什么什么’ in questions?

**Update:**

Found one more version:

> 他是个老师。

Which is said to be informal [at this link](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/7371037).

Comment: 他是一泡老师 -or- 他是一尊老师 for comedic effect.

Comment: @user3306356 , "他是一尊老师" this is a nice example :)

Comment: There's also [他当老师](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/27715/8099).

Answer (score 2):

In English, an article such as "a", "an", "the" is essential element before a countable noun. In Chinese it is optional.

Comparing "He is a teacher" with "他是老師". 他/He implies there is one person. "a" is redundant.

In "他是一位老師" and "他是一名老師",  "一位" and "一名" is a kind of respect to a teacher. 位 means position and rank. 名 means famed.  In the old days, Chinese showed their high respect to teachers.

"一個" is a common measuring word. Saying "他是一個老師" is like treating a teacher as a common object or a common person.

In practical, 一 is redundant and people often say "他是位老師" and "他是名老師". So do "他是個老師".

In Classical Chinese, we can writing "他是一老師" if we emphasize it it "one".

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your two example sentences, I believe that the difference is a matter of respect.

- 名 : a person or a member of a group
- 位 : a person (showing respect)

Aside from that there should not be any difference.

Source: http://www.ctcfl.ox.ac.uk/Grammar%20exercises/Measure%20words.htm