# I want to understand if I can use 做 instead of 当？

Tags: word-choice, word

> 我一毕业就去上海“当”律师
> This sentence is given to me in the book.
> However, I wonder if I can write it like this instead of using another word:

> 我一毕业就去上海”做“律师？

I think the meaning is the same, but which is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

当 is grammarly correct, it means "to be"

当...（职业）is the correct expression. for example:

当老师，当医生，当科学家, and it cannot be replaced by 做.

做, means "do", is to ask someone's occupation. for example:

你是做什么的？what you do for a living? it cannot be replaced by 当.

so 我一毕业就去上海”做“律师？ is a strange way to say but we also understand.

BTW, I think most of the problems asked in this Chinese Language section is simply because you guys don't have the context or not familiar with the convention.

Answer (score 1):

当 is a verb that means 'to be/ working as/ take on the role or position of' when it is followed by an identity

Examples: 当好人，当警察，当媒人，当法官

做 means 'do' or 'perform' when it is followed by a task. e.g. 做法事，做宣传，做工木，做手术. But when it is followed by an identity, it is almost interchangeable with 当 (当 being more formal)

Examples: 做好人，做警察，做媒人，做法官

Mandarin usually use 当 for 'working as/ take on the role or position of', but some regions prefer 做. (Cantonese use 做 instead )

Related question: [What's the difference between 我是老师 or 我当老师?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/27715/whats-the-difference-between-%E6%88%91%E6%98%AF%E8%80%81%E5%B8%88-or-%E6%88%91%E5%BD%93%E8%80%81%E5%B8%88)

Comment: Quote:- "Cantonese use 做 instead" So do the Hakka. It actually sounds strange using 当 in Hakka in the context of OP's question. There is also the term "当做", meaning to regard or to pretend something or someone as some other.

Comment: 当 in 当做 is a different usage of 当; Cantonese never say 当律师 instead of 做律师. My impression is, Mandarin is another way around